# What's the big-O complexity of this recursive algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I am following a course of Algorithms and Data Structures.

Today, my professor said the complexity of the following algorithm is 2<sup>n</sup>.

I waited till the lesson was over, approached him and told him I actually believed it was an `O(n)` algorithm, and I did the computation to prove it, and wanted to show them to it, but he continued to say it was not, without giving me any convincing explanation.

The algorithm is recursive, and it has this complexity:

```
       { 1         if n=1
T(n) = {
       { 2T(n/2)   otherwise
```

I computed it down to be a `O(n)`, this way:

Let's expand `T(n)`

```
T(n) = 2 [2 * T(n/(2^2))]
     = 2^2 * T(n/(2^2))
     = 2^2 * [2 * T(n/(2^3))]
     = 2^3 * T(n/(2^3))
     = ...
     = 2^i * T(n/(2^i)).
```

We stop when the term inside the T is 1, that is:

n/(2<sup>i</sup>) = 1  ==>  n = 2<sup>i</sup>  ==>  i = log n

After the substitution, we obtain

```
T(n) = 2^log n * T(1)
     = n * 1
     = O(n).
```

Since this algorithm jumped out of a lesson on Merge Sort, I noted how Merge Sort, which notoriously is `O(n log n)` has a complexity of 2T(n/2) + Θ(n) (obviously higher than 2T(n/2)), and I asked him why is it, that an algorithm with a lower complexity, gets a higher big-O. Because, at this point, it's counter intuitive for me. He replied, words for words, "If you think that is counter-intuitive, you have serious problem in your math."

My questions are:

1. Is there any fallacy in my demonstration?
2. Wouldn't the last situation be counter-intuitive?

---

Yes, this is also a vent.

Comment: If he said that it is `O(2^n)`, he is right because `O` is for an upper limit. If he thinks that it is in `Theta(2^n)`, he is wrong.

Comment: Even though I gave an answer (based on the given recurrence) it would still help if you edit your post to give the algorithm under discussion. In other words -- what *is* "the following algorithm"?

Comment: @JohnColeman I just commented under your answer about that. I'll copy it here: Prof. C. didn't actually got that recurrence relation from an algorithm. At first, as I wrote previously, I thought it was to show us that there was something counter-intuitive between the Merge-Sort recurrence relation and this one. But it became clear it wasn't when I later asked. Now I really am confused about why he showed us that.

Comment: @helpYou Yeah :D Thank you. I wasn't thinking about that. Would he be right to say it is not an O(n), though?

Comment: It is in O(n), O(2^n), O(n^n), O(nlogn), etc. but not in O(logn), O(sqrt(n)), O(1), etc. So, he is wrong if he says that it is not in `O(n)`, but he is right if he says that it is in `O(2^n)` because it is true, even if this isn't too relevant.

Comment: `"If you think that is counter-intuitive, you have serious problem in your math."` This is so unprofessional from him. No teacher should say things like this and not giving any explanation. I

Answer (score 3):

**Proof - 1**

This recurrence falls in case - 3 of [Master Theorem,](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m19w03/public_html/Section5-2.pdf) with

- a = 2;
- b = 2; and,
- c = -∞

and thus Log<sub>b</sub>a = 1 which is bigger than -∞. Therefore the running time is **Θ(n<sup>1</sup>) = Θ(n)**.

---

**Proof - 2**

Intuitively, you are breaking the problem of size *n* into 2 problems of size *n/2* and the cost to join the result of two sub-problems is 0 (i.e. there is no constant component in the recurrence).

Hence at the bottom-most level you have **n problems of cost 1** each, resulting in the running time of **n * O(1)** which is equal to **O(n)**.

---

**Edit:** Just to complete this answer I will also add the answers to specific questions asked by you.

> Is there any fallacy in my demonstration?

No. It is correct.

> Wouldn't the last situation be counter-intuitive?

Definitely it is counter-intuitive. See the Proof-2 above.

Answer (score 2):

You are clearly correct that a function `T(n)` which satisfies that recurrence relation is `O(n)`. It is essentially obvious since it says that the complexity of a given problem is twice that of a problem which is half the size. You can't get much more linear than that. For example -- the complexity of searching through a list of 1000 elements with a linear search is twice that of searching through a list with 500 elements.

If your professor is also correct then perhaps you are incorrect about the complexity satisfying that recurrence. Alternatively, sometimes there is some confusion about how the input size is being measured. For example, an integer `n` is exponential in the number of bits needed to specify it. For example -- brute force trial division of an integer `n` is `O(sqrt(n))` which is much better than `O(n)`. The reason that this doesn't contradict that fact that brute force factoring is essentially worthless for e.g. cracking RSA is because for say a 256 bit key the relevant `n` is around `2^256`.

Comment: Prof. C. didn't actually got that recurrence relation from an algorithm. He just wrote it on the whiteboard and told us it was `O(2^n)`. At first, as I wrote previously, I thought it was to show us that there was something counter-intuitive between the Merge-Sort recurrence relation and this one. But it became clear it wasn't when I later asked. Now I really am confused about why he showed us that. Anyway, your last sentence is intriguing, could you elaborate a bit more on that, please?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in computing the time complexity of the given relation. If we are measuring the input size in `n`(which we should) then your professor is wrong in claiming that the time complexity is `2^n`.

You should probably discuss it with him and clear any misunderstanding that you might have.

Comment: I will certainly do it tomorrow. Thanks.